# How to create zip file that contains jar

Tags: java, jar, zip

I can create a jar using 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/CreateJarfile.htm

I want to create a zip file. The zip file should have a folder "test" and put the jar inside folder "test". How can I do? any snippets for this.

Comment: Are you trying to use Java to create the zip file and put your generated `jar` file inside it? In that case, the jar file is totally irrelevant here, and your question becomes "How do I create a zip file using Java?" which has certainly been answered a hundred times.

Comment: It is ridiculously annoying when users ask for *"snippets"* of something extremely specific, when all they really want is someone to write something for them. Break your problem down into steps and solve each one. This is not difficult.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yea you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it.It is very Useful link you can provide a zar file for zip file.Suppose you have a abc(zar file) and test is zip folder name.Then in this link code is given so somewhere you can find file file1,file2,there you can provide your file abc
[ZarInsideZip](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/creating_zip_and_jar_files)